# Generics preventing virtual function call?

Tags: c#, generics, visual-studio-2019, vtable, c#-8.0

I'm brushing up on my C# after many years.  I'm very rusty so this may be me not the compiler.

Virtual function calls seem to stop working as I'd expect with generics.  Here's the code:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1 {

    public abstract class Root {
        // force me to implenent ToString() in subclasses
        public abstract new string ToString();
    }

    public class Mammal : Root {
        string m;
        public Mammal(string mIn) { m = mIn; }
        public override string ToString() => m;
    }

    // allow me to give a mammal a name:
    public class NamedMammal : Root {
        Mammal m; string name;
        public NamedMammal(Mammal mIn, string nameIn) {
            m = mIn; name = nameIn;
        }
        public override string ToString() =>
            $"({m.ToString()} has name {name})";
    }

    // but I may want to name many things, so make 
    //the thing being named generic:
    public class NamedThing<Tthing> : Root {
        Tthing thing; string name;
        public NamedThing(Tthing thingIn, string nameIn) {
            thing = thingIn; name = nameIn;
        }
        public override string ToString() =>
            $"({thing.ToString()} has name {name})";
    }
    // I can name tractors or planets if I want to now

    class Program {
        static void Main() {

            Mammal c = new Mammal("cow");
            NamedMammal nm = new NamedMammal(c, "daisy");
            Console.WriteLine(nm.ToString());
            // output, as expected:
            // (cow has name daisy)
            
            Mammal f = new Mammal("fox");
            NamedThing<Mammal> nt = 
                new NamedThing<Mammal>(f, "freddie");
            Console.WriteLine(nt.ToString());
            // not what I expected:
            // (ConsoleApp1.Mammal has name freddie)
        }
    }
}
```

It's clearly not lost the type because it outputting it as 'ConsoleApp1.Mammal' so it knows it's a mammal but it doesn't seem to be calling ToString() on it as I'd expect. I'd guess it's calling the base-most object ToString() instead of the most derived.

Is this as designed, if so could someone give me some pointers, and perhaps an idea of how to deal with this because I don't want to handwrite buckets of boilerplate.

Comment: It's calling `object.ToString()`, because you don't constrain your `Tthing` to `Root`, so it defaults to `object`'s methods. The compiler doesn't know that your `Tthing` has a new `ToString()` method.

Comment: Because you are using `new`, calling the default implementation of `ToString` is not going to work. If you want to force your derived classes to override `ToString` you should have used `public override abstract string ToString();`

Comment: @CodeCaster: AFAIK the compiler does know, that's because of the 'new' in ToString() in root. Comment out the ToString() in 'public class NamedThing<Tthing>  and you'll get compiler error "'NamedThing<Tthing>' does not implement inherited abstract member 'Root.ToString()'".

Comment: @DavidG: that worked! Thanks

Comment: _"the compiler does know"_ - yes, if you inherit it, such as the `NamedThing<Tthing> : Root`. But you don't constrain the generic type `Tthing`, so for _that_ type, the compiler doesn't know that the type you pass it inherits from anything, so it defaults to `object` until you specify.

Comment: Use member hiding with extreme caution.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the methods `object.ToString()` and `Root.ToString()` are not related in any way. Which is by your design.

In the class `NamedMammal` you expect a *thing* of type `Mammal` which implements `Root`. So the compiler know that the method `Root.ToString()` is guaranteed to be present on the given instance. Then in the `NamedMammal.ToString()` method you are calling the `Root.ToString()` implementation of `Mammal` because it is shadowing (not overriding) the `object.ToString()`.

But for the `NamedThing` class your *thing* does not necessary implement `Root.ToString()` so in the method `NamedThing.ToString()` the call `thing.ToString()` will call `object.ToString()`. This does not result in the invokation of the `Root.ToString()` method because it is not an overriding virutal method for `object.ToString()`.

A solution for this would be to condition the type parameter of `NamedThing` to implement `Root` like:

```cs
public class NamedThing<Tthing> : Root where Tthing : Root 
{ .. }
```

Another solution would be to replace the `new` in

```
public abstract new string ToString();
```

with `override`

```
public abstract override string ToString();
```

that way the implementing types override `object.ToString()` and not an unrelated similar named method.

---

But be aware that you need at least the first solution to force the types being used with `NamedThing` to implement `ToString()`.

Comment: Perhaps mention the possibility of avoiding `new` to stop the shadowing?

Comment: Ackdari: I've accepted your answer as I can see the subtyping (Root where Tthing : Root) makes sense and I see without it why it would go to Object instead. I'll go through the rest and try to understand. Like I said, I'm very rusty and C# has grown a lot. Thanks also to @DavidG